# passing values using hivevar in HIVE

Tags: hive

I've got a param which is like `"This is a param"`, and I'm going to pass it to below hiveQL:

```
hive -hivevar sys_nm="This is a param" -e 'select * from rd_sys where rd_sys_nm=${hivevar:sys_nm}'
```

But Hive returned below error message:

> Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/mapr/hive/hive-0.13/lib/hive-common-0.13.0-mapr-1409.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
>   `FAILED:` ParseException line 1:49 missing EOF at 'is' near 'This'
>   g4t7491_[mgr@g4t7491 ~]$

Does anyone know how to pass it normally?

Answer (score 0):

Hive var don't work like hiveconf where you need to apply "hiveconf:somthing" in the code
when declaring hivevar just add the var name like this -> ${var_name}

for example:
through command line:

```
hive -hivevar MONTH_VAR='11' -e "select * from table where month=${MONTH_VAR};"
```

you can also declair through the script:

```
set hivevar:MONTH_VAR=11;
```

-- so query would look like this (no hiveconf):

```
set hivevar:MONTH_VAR=11;
SELECT * from table where month=${MONTH_VAR};
```

Comment: thanks Amit, how should I pass it if param value has space in it? Any ideas?

Comment: I believe that if it's a string you can pass it using normal apostrophe (') (not quotes), and if that doesn't work you could use the special  apostrophe located above the tab (`) which is the linux apostrophe

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the string in single quotes for it to parse correctly as a string inside the sql after interpolation.

```
hive -hivevar sys_nm="'This is a param'" -e 'select * from rd_sys where rd_sys_nm=${hivevar:sys_nm}'
```